# Load Terms - typescript error - spfx term store taxonomy

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I am trying to retrieve all the terms for a term-set in my term store to be used in an SPFx web part.

Following the guide given [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp-taxonomy/docs/terms/).

```
// get terms merged with data from a term set
const terms4: (ITerm & ITermData)[] = store.getTermSetById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").terms.get();
```

This line is failing due:

> Type 'Promise<(ITermData & ITerm)[]>' is missing the following properties from type '(ITerm & ITermData)[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more.ts(2740)

Any idea how to fix that?

Full code:

```
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.getTerms();
  }

  public async getTerms() {
    const store: ITermStore = await taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_O1cHqzMmDZNz4UeaKJLVpA==");

    const labelMatchInfo: ILabelMatchInfo = {
        TermLabel: "My Label",
        TrimUnavailable: true,
    };

    const terms: ITerms = store.getTerms(labelMatchInfo);

    // get term instances merged with data
    const terms2: (ITermData & ITerm)[] = await store.getTerms(labelMatchInfo).get();

    const terms3: ITerms = store.getTermSetById("6a488843-cebc-47b7-8606-e4e165e6fceb").terms;

    // get terms merged with data from a term set
    const terms4: (ITerm & ITermData)[] = store.getTermSetById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").terms.get();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding await fixed it! (microsoft should update the docs)

Fix:

```
// get terms merged with data from a term set
const terms4: (ITerm & ITermData)[] = await store.getTermSetById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431").terms.get();
```